# SSRS 2008 drill through subtotal and grand total parameters

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, parameter-passing, ssrs-2008-r2, drillthrough

I have a drill through report I'm creating in SSRS (SQL Server 2008 R2).  The parameter pass-through to my detail report works fine for any normal detail row in the summary report tables, however the subtotal and grand total rows only pass the first value from that row to the detail report as a parameter.

So, if my summary report looks like this:

```
Row A  values, values, values
Row B  values, values, values
Subtotal1 values, values, values
Row C  values, values, values
Row D  values, values, values
Subtotal2  values, values, values
Grand Total  values, values, values
```

Obviously, if you click on a value in Row A, "Row A" gets passed as a parameter to the Detail report, but when I click on a Subtotal or Grand Total row, only Row A gets passed as a parameter.  How do I get those values to pass the relative combination of parameters (Subtotal1 = "Row A, Row B")?

Under the Text Box Properties / Action / Parameter value expressions, I've currently got:

```
= Fields!ParamName.Value
```

I've tried:

```
= Join(Fields!ParamName.Value, ",") or = Split(Join(Fields!ParamName.Value, ","), ",")
```

as I've seen in other posts, but both of those give me an "Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Join' can be called with these arguments" error.

Comment: I think we have similar issues. See if my unansered post code example helps you any.  I am having issue now with the subtotals passing each value for each column.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993462/ssrs-how-to-pass-multiple-field-column-values-from-a-collapsed-column-while-do

Comment: Have you looked at RunningTotal solutions?   Maybe it can be adapted to keep a concatenated string value?